# App crashes in Retina enabled device with low memory warning But in works perfect in non retina devices

Tags: iphone, xcode, cocos2d-iphone

I am developing a cocos2d game which is retina enabled . I have added lots of images in my project for both retina and non retina. Game works fine in simulator [Both retina and non retina], and it also works perfect in non retina devices. But when i run the same in the retina enabled device means it get's crashed without displaying any message. When i test my game with instrument application means it shows low memory warning message  like this [http://screencast.com/t/sfRDTELrhomC]. When the app get's crash While running in the retina enabled device it's doesn't show any error message in the console. I am terribly confused with the current state can anyone help me out with this problem.

Comment: You can simulate memory warnings in the simulator, it's under the Hardware menu. Make sure to enable Exception breakpoints, and try again, you might see where the crash happens

Comment: are you using ImageNamed method to display images?

Comment: @ SmartWork No i am not using any sorts of method like that

Comment: it is rather standard app behaviour in case of not enough memory. and it always means that you have to reduce memory usage by unload unused textures, sounds, or reduce number of textures on your scene

Comment: @ Morion I searched if there is any unused texture in my game . But dint found any of them. Is there is any other solution for this

Answer (score 0):

You are probably using a lot of memory to load images, so the device runs out of memory and kills your application.

I'm guessing you are using PNGs (since you didn't give any info on this); when you load an image from PNG, JPG, etc., the image is loaded into memory twice, since it has to be "translated" by cocos into a texture. Also, texture sizes for this operation has to be a power of 2, so an image of 150x150 would take the memory of an image of 256x256. This is a lot of wasted memory.

My first suggestion is to buy Texture Packer (I'm in no way affiliated with them, it's just a great piece of software), which takes your images and makes them into a compressed PVR sprite sheets that contain several images in one texture.

PVR files are loaded directly into a texture, so they don't use double memory, and since they are sprite sheets, you have less wasted pixels.

My second suggestion is to, when loading your images, not do it all in the same tick of the runloop; Cocos uses a lot of autoreleases, and that memory is not cleared until the end of the tick, so instead of loading all images into memory in the same method at once, schedule that method to be called several times and load a new file every time.

Comment: PS. This is not going to be a walk in the park. It's gonna take some work.